# How to calculate values in an R dataframe when columns are dependent on each other

Tags: r, dataframe

First time poster - so apologies if this question is basic/poorly explained. Grateful to anyone can help or point me in the right direction!

I would like to do the following within an R dataframe if possible:

*Existing Data*

Column A is a vector of values, say 10 to 20.

*New Data/columns*

Column B will be be Column A multiplied by Column C

Column C will be Column C minus Column B from the previous row of data, i.e data$C[-1] - data$B[-1], apart the first row of Column C of course, which I will give a fixed value.

I have tried these as separate steps, but I keep overwriting columns B and C, and have a feeling I have been going about this the wrong way! I could share my code, but I think this would confuse matters!

Thanks in advance!

EDIT TO ADD CODE:

```
A <- c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5)
df1 <- data.frame(A)

df1$B <- 0 
df1$C <- 0 

df1$C[1] <- 100

df2 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(B = C * A,
         C = lag(C-B))
```

RESULT FROM THE ABOVE

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.1 | 10 | *NA* |
| 2 | 0.2 | 0 | 90 |
| 3 | 0.3 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0.4 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 0.5 | 0 | 0 |

EXPECTED OUTPUT

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.1 | 10 | 100 |
| 2 | 0.2 | 18 | 90 |
| 3 | 0.3 | 21.6 | 72 |
| 4 | 0.4 | 20.16 | 50.4 |
| 5 | 0.5 | 15.12 | 30.24 |

C2 = C1 - B1
B2 = C2 * A2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `accumulate` from `purrr` to do recursive update

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
tmp <-  with(df1, accumulate(A,  ~ .x - (.x * .y), .init = first(C)))
df2 <- df1 %>% 
    mutate(C = head(tmp, -1), B = -diff(tmp))
df2
#    A     B      C
#1 0.1 10.00 100.00
#2 0.2 18.00  90.00
#3 0.3 21.60  72.00
#4 0.4 20.16  50.40
#5 0.5 15.12  30.24
```

---

Or use `base R`

```
tmp <- with(df1, Reduce(function(x, y) x - (x * y), A, 
     accumulate = TRUE, init = C[1]))
df2 <- transform(df1, C = head(tmp, -1), B = -diff(tmp))
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I am almost there. I changed your code above slightly to lag(C-B), see below. 

However, C1 changes to NA (but I would like this to stay as 100), and I am still getting 0 for the other values. Ideally I would like to get 18 (0.2*90) in B2, and 72 (90-18) in C3. And so on. Sorry if I have missed something!

A <- c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5)
df1 <- data.frame(A)

df1$B <- 0 
df1$C <- 0 

df1$C[1] <- 100

df2 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(B = C * A,
         C = lag(C-B))

Comment: @Tyingtocode without a reproducible example, it is difficult to test

Comment: I have added the code above to my initial post above, along with the resulting table. Does this help as a reproducible example? The only values I am plugging into this test is vector A.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Tyingtocode can you update your post with expected output

Comment: @Tyingtocode I updated the post.  For the 'C' column, I am not sure about the values.  Can you please check

Comment: I have added the expected output above, and it looks like you're first mutate command is very close! Just seeing if I can edit to fully replicate the table.

Comment: @Tyingtocode please check the updated answer

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a mathematical approach, you can first derive the general expression for the recursion and then have the R code afterwards.

Below is one implementation with base R

```
transform(
  transform(
    df1,
    C = C[1] * c(1, cumprod(1 - A)[-nrow(df1)])
  ),
  B = A * C
)
```

which gives

```
    A     B      C
1 0.1 10.00 100.00
2 0.2 18.00  90.00
3 0.3 21.60  72.00
4 0.4 20.16  50.40
5 0.5 15.12  30.24
```

---

A `data.table` option in a similar manner is

```
> setDT(df1)[, C := first(C) * c(1, cumprod(1 - A)[-.N])][, B := A * C][]
     A     B      C
1: 0.1 10.00 100.00
2: 0.2 18.00  90.00
3: 0.3 21.60  72.00
4: 0.4 20.16  50.40
5: 0.5 15.12  30.24
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for these other options!